# Login instagram using python

Tags: python, web, authentication

I am having my own project to create a instagram bot. The first thin i need to do is to create a login. I created the below python script to login the instagram. However, it returns 403 status code to me. Anyone can give some advice on what's wrong?

```
import requests
import json
import random
import time

Base_url = 'https://www.instagram.com/'
Login_url = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/'
Username = 'username'
Passowrd = 'password'
User_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'
login_data = {'username': Username, 'password': Passowrd}

session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update({
            'Accept': '*/*',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'Content-Length': '0',
            'Host': 'www.instagram.com',
            'Origin': 'https://www.instagram.com',
            'Referer': 'https://www.instagram.com/',
            'User-Agent': User_agent,
            'X-Instagram-AJAX': '1',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
        })

req = session.get(Base_url)
session.headers.update({'X-CSFRToken': req.cookies['csrftoken']})
time.sleep(5 * random.random())

login = session.post(Login_url, data=login_data, allow_redirects = True )
session.headers.update({'X-CSFRToken': login.cookies['csrftoken']})
csrftoken = login.cookies['csrftoken']
#ig_vw=1536; ig_pr=1.25; ig_vh=772;  ig_or=landscape-primary;
session.cookies['ig_vw'] = '1536'
session.cookies['ig_pr'] = '1.25'
session.cookies['ig_vh'] = '772'
session.cookies['ig_or'] = 'landscape-primary'
time.sleep(5 * random.random())
print(login.status_code)

if login.status_code == 200:
    #login_text_notjson = login.text
    print('sucessfully login')

    try:
        login_text = json.loads(login.text)

    except Exception:
        print('there is an error')

    else:
        #print(login_text_notjson)
        print(login_text)

else: 
    print('you fail to login')
```

Very grateful if anyone can give me the information about creating a bot for that. I still have no idea why my user_agent didn't work for that.

Comment: Maybe your username and password are not valid? Maybe you're missing some other header that instagram requires for this specific call. I'm asusming instagram specifically don't want to allow scripted calls to their API like this, so there are all sorts of things that might be preventing this. Are you able to make/see the login call working as an ajax request from your browser?

Comment: Could you use the supported API instead? https://developers.facebook.com/products/instagram/

Answer (score 1):

This will allow you to login to instagram (python3) - can be easily edited for your class

```
          self.s.headers.update({
                'accept': '*/*',
                'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
                'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
                'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'origin': 'https://www.instagram.com',
                'referer': 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/',
                'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.3; en-us; HTC_DesireS_S510e Build/GRI40) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1',
                'x-instagram-ajax': '1',
                'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
        })
        Grab = self.s.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/")
        self.s.headers.update({"x-csrftoken": Grab.cookies.get_dict()['csrftoken']})

        LoginData = {
            'username': Username,
            'password': Password,
            'queryParams': '{}'
        }
        AccLogin = self.s.post("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/",
data=LoginData)
        if AccLogin.json()['authenticated']:
            self.s.headers.update({"x-csrftoken": AccLogin.cookies.get_dict()['csrftoken']})
```